# Twitter upload media - Could not authenticate you

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have a problem when trying to upload a photo to twitter. I use twitteroauth.php to authenticate, and I have no problem posting a tweet through the api, or receiving data. But when I want to upload a photo, i get the following error: {"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}

This is my code:

```
<?php
require_once('../include/initialize.php');

require_once('twitter/twitteroauth.php');

if(isset($_GET['access_token']) && $_GET['access_token'] != ''){
  $accesstoken = $_GET['access_token'];
}else{
  $accesstoken = TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN;
}

if(isset($_GET['access_token_secret']) && $_GET['access_token_secret'] != ''){
  $accesstokensecret = $_GET['access_token_secret'];
}else{
  $accesstokensecret = TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET;
}

$consumerkey = TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY;
$consumersecret = TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET;
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

$url = $_POST['url'];
$filename = $_POST['filename'];

// function to replace file_get_contents()
function file_get_the_contents($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5; // set to zero for no timeout
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$file_contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $file_contents;
}

// original script updated with new function
$imgget = file_get_the_contents($url);

$twitter_api = "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json?media=".$imgget."&type=photo";

$twitter_img = $twitter->post($twitter_api);

echo json_encode($twitter_img);
```

Can anybody help me with this issue. I have looked around on forums, but all other issues I find are referring to the statuses/update_with_media which is deprecated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Twitter api upload image always return error "media type unrecognized"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536867/twitter-api-upload-image-always-return-error-media-type-unrecognized)

Answer (score 2):

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31888260/9608521) answer by [toster-cx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1895684/toster-cx), you need to make sure that you encode the image data in base 64. Otherwise, Twitter will respond with error 32. You will need something like this:

```php
$imgget = base64_encode(file_get_the_contents($url));
```