# Twitter api upload image always return error "media type unrecognized"

Tags: php, twitter, upload, twitter-rest-api

I do POST-request on https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json
with postfield

```
'media_data' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($path))
```

twitter api always return error "media type unrecognized".

what's wrong?

I tried to change postfield to those versions:

```
'media_data' => 'data:image/'.$type.';base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($path)),
'media' => file_get_contents($path),
'media' => realpath($path)...
```

file formats: jpeg, jpg

Comment: Are you POSTing with a `multipart/form-data` request?

Comment: I posting with CURL. I am using TwitterAPIExchange library (http://github.com/j7mbo/twitter-api-php)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why *media* wasn't working for you, but *media_data* has to be used without the header. I've used it this way and it works.

```
'media_data' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($path));
```

https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/blob/1.0.5/test/TwitterAPIExchangeTest.php#L174-L181