# Twitter api error "code 32 Could not authenticate you" when trying to upload images

Tags: qt, authentication, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am trying to upload photos to twitter from my app and i am using https://github.com/pipacs/o2 library for OAuth.

The following is the code that i am using:

```
QFile file(imgPath);
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        return false;
    }
QByteArray m_buffer = file.readAll();

O1Requestor* requestor = new O1Requestor(d->netMngr, d->o1Twitter, this);
QList<O0RequestParameter> reqParams = QList<O0RequestParameter>();

reqParams << O0RequestParameter(QByteArray("media"), m_buffer);
reqParams << O0RequestParameter(QByteArray("media_type"), QByteArray("image/jpeg"));

QByteArray postData = O1::createQueryParameters(reqParams);

QUrl url = QUrl("https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json");
QNetworkRequest request(url);

request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, O2_MIME_TYPE_XFORM);
QNetworkReply *reply = requestor->post(request, reqParams, postData);
```

The result is the following:

> ERROR: "Host requires authentication"
>       Content: "{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}"

I tried doing something simple like posting a tweet saying Hello to test the authentication using statuses/update endpoint and it worked with no errors.
The following is the code also if it is required:

```
QUrl url2 = QUrl("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json);

reqParams = QList<O0RequestParameter>();
reqParams << O0RequestParameter(QByteArray("status"), "Hello");
postData = O1::createQueryParameters(reqParams);

request.setUrl(url2);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, O2_MIME_TYPE_XFORM);
QNetworkReply *reply = requestor->post(request, reqParams, postData);
```

Could you please help me with this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31888260/9608521) answer, you will need to ensure that the image content in `m_buffer` is sent as a base-64 encoded string. Otherwise, the Twitter API will return error 32.